# Is there a way to error check for $stmt->bind_param?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Below is my code for a new form submission on a page. I've been working on this all day and the statement keeps failing on bind_param.

```
$query = "  INSERT INTO table
                                    (   
                                        AbandonedComments,                                          
                                        DetectorComments,                                           
                                        FireExComments,                                         
                                        PestComments,                                       
                                        SanitationComments
                                    )
                                VALUES
                                    (   
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?;
                                    )";   
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);   
                $stmt->bind_param("sssss",
                        $_POST['GeneralComment'],
                        $_POST['SmokeDetectorComment'],
                        $_POST['fireExComments'],
                        $_POST['PestComments'],
                        $_POST['SanitationComments']
                );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

I've wrapped that section in a try/catch, an if/else, and have tested to see if values are coming through.

- The try/catch did not catch, but it did not succeed either
- The if/else ran neither.
- All values are being passed accordingly.

I know the execute() can be error checked as it returns a boolean value, but I have not found anything on the bind_param.

EDIT: I talked to my boss right after posting this, he pointed out the error and explained that there is no error checking for 'bind_param' but that both 'prepare' and 'execute' will return boolean and that you can check there.

Comment: _Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure._ http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: *"Is there a way to error check for $stmt->bind_param?"* - I've answered a question like this before and there is no way to check for errors on `bind_param()`; I just need to find it.

Comment: Maybe something else failed, what is this `?;`

Comment: You check for errors on the "query", not the binding.

Comment: Errors from most built-in functions don't throw errors, they just return a special value like `FALSE` that you have to check for.

Answer (score 4):

```
 VALUES
                                    (   
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?; <<< trailing semi-colon
```

Notice the semi-colon in there?

Reason why it didn't throw an error is because in PHP and other languages, is considered as being a valid character, being an "end of statement" and is located at the end of your all your placeholders (consult the edit).

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.

You state that the query (bind) failed; it either failed with a reason and you didn't check for the real error, or it failed silently which can happen.

You also can't check for errors on the bind, you check for errors on the query and with error reporting should this also be a PHP-related issue.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Edit:

However, had your query read something like:

```
 VALUES
                                    (   
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?; <<< trailing semi-colon                                         
                                        ?
                                     )";
```

...then that would be an entirely different ballgame, since the last placeholder never gets used and the statement stops at the 4th placeholder.

You could and should use a conditional statement by modifiying your present  `$stmt->execute();` statement to and using the `!` which is the "not" operator, which translates to something like *"if the query did not execute"*:

```
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}else{
    echo "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Syntax checking is done when you call `prepare()`, not `bind_param()`.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query) or die($mysqli->error);
```

However, `bind_param()` should have reported an error because `$stmt` would be `FALSE`. It should have complained about calling a method on a non-object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a semicolon inserted wrongly

```
VALUES
                                    (   
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?,                                          
                                        ?**;**
                                    )"
```

Comment: Ok good catch, but..... there is a reason why it didn't throw an error; do you know why? I do. I'd like you to find it and explain it.

Comment: This is the right answer, I just can't accept it yet. The query works!

Comment: @Liam so why did you and remove the semi-colon in the edit?? https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46736498/3 this answer doesn't hold true to the now existing question. Edit Ok stop editing. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46736498/3

Comment: I returned it @Fred-ii- (sorry about that). I still would like to know if there are other error checking methods for a prepared statement.

Comment: @Liam only http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php on the query. Both Barmar and I have posted new answers for you to consult.

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmar shows, if you don't enable exceptions, then you must check **every mysqli call** for a response of `false`. IIRC, every mysqli function does return false on error.

You should just configure mysqli to raise exceptions for prepare() errors. This is not its default setting, so you have to enable it. But it's not obvious how to do it from the documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php shows an example.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$link = mysqli_connect(...);
```

After you do this, then your prepare() should have raised an exception because of the SQL syntax error, the extra semicolon in your values clause that others have pointed out.

I'm always surprised how few people enable exceptions with mysqli. I guess they just didn't notice the part about mysqli_report() in the docs. It's really pretty buried.

It seems to be more common for developers who use PDO to enable exceptions. This is also not enabled by default, but it's easier to find in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php